# Restful Webservice SAP testing

Tags: rest, web-services, testing, abap

Is there any way to test rest Webservices in SAP?

I know it's possible to test SOAP Webservices with eCATT but to do that a WSDL file is needed.
The Problem with rest Webservices is, there is no such WSDL file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the language of the client's code which will invoke sap rest ws.

Comment: You can test using SOAPUI. REST adapter is also available in PI now. You can use that also. There is something called WADL (Web Application Description Language), which can be generated for REST web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that you'd like to test the service from within your SAP system rather than by using an external tool.

If you have access to a system that has the Gateway components deployed, you can use the [Gateway client](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/06/2dfe50645c741ae10000000a423f68/content.htm) (transaction code `/IWFND/GW_CLIENT`). It provides a very similar set of functionality to Postman, Paw, et al.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some rest clients available on the browsers:

1. Postman -> Chrome
2. RESTClient -> Firefox

Futhermore, if you need a more robust client, you can use SoapUI. See this [link](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

[Here](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/testing-asp-net-web-apiget-post-put-delete-using-fiddler/) is detailed instructions on how to test a web service (I know the instructions are for asp.net web services but the Fiddler part should work for any web services).